# Best search method for short arrays

Tags: arrays, performance, search

I have a lot of short arrays(10-20 elements). What is best way(i mean speed) to found one element in each array? Binary search, tries, hashtable etc?

Comment: @Benj i can represent data in any way.

Comment: Best method would be to store it so you always put the one you're looking for at the front of the array. Problem solved.

Comment: If your arrays are short, then definitely not hashtable.

Comment: @awoodland  I need to search different data many times.

Comment: The answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524032/binary-search-efficiency-vs-linear-search-efficiency-in-fortran - may be instructive.

Answer (score 1):

Measure at least three approaches:

1. Linear search
2. Binary search
3. Hashtable

Measure them for different input sizes and choose the best method at runtime depending on the size of the array.

You could also investigate perfect hashing which trades a big upfront calculation that only needs to be done once for very fast lookup.

Comment: The Binary Search also has to be thoroughly _tested_.