# Map N integers to [1,N]

Tags: algorithm, fortran

I'm looking for an efficient way to map a N integers to [1,N].

The N integers are actually entries of a sorted array A with no redundancies, and my goal is to be able to simply access the index of every entry of the array.

Example :

For a given array A of integers, sorted and without redundancies, but with gaps and possibly very large numbers (you could have 1000 integers ranging from 25 to 10^6), I need a way of finding the index of every entry in an efficient way. For example if A[15] = 1546, I need to be able to do index(1546) = 15. 
My problem is that I need to do this in Fortran, and as far as I know, there are no real hash table libraries.

Comment: For a sorted array with no redundancies (for example A = [2,4,7,23]), I want to be able to access the index of every entry (i.e. A_inverse(7) = 3.). I don't really have a code to show as it is more of a general problem. It just so happens that I need to do this in Fortran.

Comment: This problem is precisely solved by a hash table, unless the range of possible values is small enough that you can create an inverted lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can use a binary search for solve your problem. It is simple for code.

Look this page [[Binary search in array issue using Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043105/binary-search-in-array-issue-using-fortran])

Using binary search you get the inverse index of the given number.