# Comparison tricks in C++

Tags: c++, comparison

A class:

```
class foo{
public:
    int data;
};
```

Now I want to add a method to this class, to do some comparison, to see if its data is equal to one of given numbers.

Of course, I can write `if(data==num1|| data == num2|| data ==num3.....)`, but honestly speaking, I feel sick when I write `data ==` every time I compare it to a number.

So, I hope I would be able to write something like this:

```
if(data is equal to one of these(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5...))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

I want to implement this statement, `data is equal to one of these(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5...)`

Here is my approach:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
bool is_equal_to_one_of_these(int count,...){
    int i;
    bool equal = false;
    va_list arg_ptr;
    va_start(arg_prt,count);
    for(int x=0;x<count;x++){
        i = va_arg(arg_ptr,int);
        if( i == data ){
            equal = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(arg_ptr);
    return equal;
}
```

This piece of code will do the job for me. But every time I use this method, I'll have to count the parameters and pass it in.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: `if (1 <= data && data <= 6)`

Comment: `$data == any(@numbers)` oh wait, that's perl 6 :P. Would be fun to simulate using operator overloading, tho

Comment: Why check for `i != data` and just continue? Why not just do a check for `i == data`, and remove the `i != data` check because the loop will just continue anyway?

Comment: My brain was kinda short when I write this code :D, I'll edit that. Thanks for pointing out ~ @TomHeard

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### The easy way

The simplest approach is to write a member function wrapper called `in()` around `std::find` with a pair of iterators to look for the data in question. I wrote a simple `template<class It> in(It first, It last)` member function for that

```
template<class It>
bool in(It first, It last) const
{
    return std::find(first, last, data) != last;
}
```

If you have no access to the source of `foo`, you can write a non-member functions of signature `template<class T> bool in(foo const&, std::initializer_list<T>)` etc., and call it like

```
in(f, {1, 2, 3 });
```

### The hard way

But let's go completely overboard  with that: just add two more `public` overloads:

- one taking a `std::initializer_list` parameter that calls the previous one with the `begin()` and `end()` iterators of the corresponding initializer list argument.
- one for an arbitrary container as input that will do a little **tag dispatching** to two more `private` overloads of a `detail_in()` helper:

  - one overload doing a SFINAE trick with trailing return type `decltype(c.find(data), bool())` that will be removed from the overload set if the container `c` in question does not have a member function `find()`, and that returns `bool` otherwise (this is achieved by abusing the **comma operator** inside `decltype`)
  - one fallback overload that simply takes the `begin()` and `end()` iterators and delegates to the original `in()` taking two iterators

Because the tags for the `detail_in()` helper form an inheritance hierarchy (much like the standard iterator tags), the first overload will match for the associative containers `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` and their multi-cousins. All other containers, including C-arrays, `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::list`, will match the second overload.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

class foo
{
public:
    int data;

    template<class It>
    bool in(It first, It last) const
    {
        std::cout << "iterator overload: ";
        return std::find(first, last, data) != last;
    }

    template<class T>
    bool in(std::initializer_list<T> il) const
    {
        std::cout << "initializer_list overload: ";
        return in(begin(il), end(il));
    }

    template<class Container>
    bool in(Container const& c) const 
    {
        std::cout << "container overload: ";
        return detail_in(c, associative_container_tag{});    
    }

private:
    struct sequence_container_tag {};
    struct associative_container_tag: sequence_container_tag {};

    template<class AssociativeContainer>
    auto detail_in(AssociativeContainer const& c, associative_container_tag) const 
    -> decltype(c.find(data), bool())
    {
        std::cout << "associative overload: ";
        return c.find(data) != end(c);    
    }

    template<class SequenceContainer> 
    bool detail_in(SequenceContainer const& c, sequence_container_tag) const
    {
        std::cout << "sequence overload: ";
        using std::begin; using std::end;
        return in(begin(c), end(c));    
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f{1};
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3};
    int a2[] = { 2, 3, 4};

    std::cout << f.in({1, 2, 3}) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in({2, 3, 4}) << "\n";

    std::cout << f.in(std::begin(a1), std::end(a1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in(std::begin(a2), std::end(a2)) << "\n";

    std::cout << f.in(a1) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in(a2) << "\n";

    std::cout << f.in(std::array<int, 3>{ 1, 2, 3 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in(std::array<int, 3>{ 2, 3, 4 }) << "\n";

    std::cout << f.in(std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in(std::vector<int>{ 2, 3, 4 }) << "\n";

    std::cout << f.in(std::set<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in(std::set<int>{ 2, 3, 4 }) << "\n";

    std::cout << f.in(std::unordered_set<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << f.in(std::unordered_set<int>{ 2, 3, 4 }) << "\n";    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b5fd476a81083a7) that -**for all possible containers**- prints 1 and 0 for both number sets.

The use cases for the `std::initializer_list` overload are for member-ship testing for **small sets** of numbers that you **write out explicitly** in calling code. It has `O(N)` complexity but avoids any heap allocations.

For anything heavy-duty like membership testing of **large sets**, you could store the numbers in an associative container like `std::set`, or its `multi_set` or `unordered_set` cousins. This will go to the heap when storing these numbers, but has `O(log N)` or even `O(1)` lookup complexity.

But if you happen to have just a sequence container full of numbers around, you can also throw that to the class and it will happily compute membership for you in `O(N)` time.

Comment: using STL is always the solution.

Comment: `initializer_list` is not part of the STL.

Comment: Why not `std::set`? That's part of STL.

Comment: I'd move `foo_in_numbers` to `foo.in(std::initializer_list<T> numbers)`. Then you can write `f.in({1,2,3})` which IMO looks a lot nicer.

Answer (score 19):

There are many ways of doing this with the STL.

If you have an incredibly large number of items and you want to test if your given item is a member of this set, use [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) or [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/). They allow you to check membership in `log n` and constant time respectively.

If you keep the elements in a sorted array, then [`binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) will also test membership in `log n` time.

For small arrays, a linear search with [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) might however preform significantly faster (as there is no branching). [A linear search might even do 3-8 comparisons in the time it takes the binary search to 'jump around'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524032/binary-search-efficiency-vs-linear-search-efficiency-in-fortran). [This blog post](http://schani.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/linear-vs-binary-search/) suggests there to be a break-even point at proximately 64 items, below which a linear search might be faster, though this obviously depends on the STL implementation, compiler optimizations and your architecture's branch prediction.

Answer (score 10):

If `data` is really an integral or enumerated type, you can use a `switch`:

```
switch (data) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 2000:
  case 6000:
  case /* whatever other values you want */:
    act_on_the_group();
    break;
  default:
    act_on_not_the_group();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The answers using `std::initializer_list` are fine, but I want to add one more possible solution which is exactly what you where trying with that C variadic in a type-safe and modern way: **Using C++11 variadic templates**:

```
template<typename... NUMBERS>
bool any_equal( const foo& f , NUMBERS&&... numbers )
{
    auto unpacked = { numbers... };

    return std::find( std::begin( unpacked ) , std::end( unpacked ) , f.data ) 
           != std::end( unpacked );
};
```

*Of course this only works if all values passed are of the same type. If not the initializer list `unpacked` cannot be deduced nor initialized.*

Then:

```
bool equals = any_equal( f , 1,2,3,4,5 );
```

**EDIT:** Here is a `are_same` metafunction to ensure that all the numbers passed are of the same type:

```
template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL>
struct are_same : public and_op<std::is_same<HEAD,TAIL>::value...>
{};
```

Where `and_op` performs n-ary logical and:

```
template<bool HEAD , bool... TAIL>
struct and_op : public std::integral_constant<bool,HEAD && and_op<TAIL...>::value>
{};

template<>
struct and_op<> : public std::true_type
{};
```

This makes possible to force the usage of numbers of the same type in a simple way:

```
template<typename... NUMBERS>
bool any_equal( const foo& f , NUMBERS&&... numbers )
{
    static_assert( all_same<NUMBERS...>::value , 
                   "ERROR: You should use numbers of the same type" );


    auto unpacked = { numbers... };

    return std::find( std::begin( unpacked ) , std::end( unpacked ) , f.data ) 
           != std::end( unpacked );
};
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to express that all NUMBERS should have the same type ? It seems like `initializer_list` is using a construct not accessible to the regular developer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. when writting recursive functions yes, putting a fixed type on the head instead of a template. But for this case we should write a custom metafunction since the standard library doesn't provide a n-ary `std::is_same`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have added an example

Comment: Or simply bypass the same type restriction: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acf1e702c4fb33b3

Answer (score 6):

Any optimization is going to depend on properties of the set of numbers being compared to.

If there's a definite upper bound, you can use a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Testing membership (that is, indexing into the bitset, which behaves like an array), is O(1), effectively a few fast instructions. This is often the best solution up to limits in the hundreds, although depending on the application millions could be practical.

Comment: Yeah, if the comparison is done several times, this is a good idea.  Still have to iterate once, but only once.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's a table lookup. I wouldn't call it an iteration.

Comment: And how, perchance, do you intend to _fill_ the table? You iterate over the numbers and set that bit in the lookup, and then you never have to iterate over the numbers again.

Comment: @MooingDuck I assumed the set is a compile-time constant. Generating the set isn't really discussed in the question, but the original problem statement used numeric literals. (Now, how to generate a large bitset is a rather large omission from this answer. IIRC, C++14 *almost* allows you to write a for-loop and still get static initialization, if done carefully. It can happen with a compliant extension of `constexpr` bitset members.)

Answer (score 4):

It isn't pretty, but this should work:

```
class foo {
    bool equals(int a) { return a == data; }
    bool equals(int a, int b) { return (a == data) || (b == data); }
    bool equals(int a, int b, int c) {...}     
    bool equals(int a, int b, int c, int d) {...} 
private:
    int data; 
}
```

And so on. That'll give you the exact syntax you were after. But if you are after the completely variable number of arguments then either the vector, or std::initalizer list might be the way to go:

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

This example shows it in action:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <initializer_list>

class foo {
public:
        foo(int d) : data(d) {}
        bool equals_one_of(std::initializer_list<int> options) {
                for (auto o: options) {
                        if (o == data) return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
private:
        int data;
};

int main() {
        foo f(10);
        assert(f.equals_one_of({1,3,5,7,8,10,14}));
        assert(!f.equals_one_of({3,6,14}));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: use `std::find`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Agreed.  I'm not normally in STL land so this is quite interesting. I'm leaning towards this very general solution: template<class T, class S>
bool contains(std::initializer_list<T> list, S value) {
 return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), value) != list.end();   
}

Comment: You can actually get even more generic: do not use a dedicated container :) `bool contains(C const& c, V const& v) { using std::begin; using std::end; return std::find(begin(c), end(c), v) != end(c); }`, though the diagnostic will be less pleasant if something else than a container is passed...

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone have better idea ? thanks for sharing !

There's a standard algitrithm for that:

```
using std::vector; // & std::begin && std::end

// if(data is equal to one of these(1,2,3,4,5,6))
/* maybe static const */vector<int> criteria{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
return end(criteria) != std::find(begin(criteria), end(criteria), data);
```

Edit: (all in one place):

```
bool is_equal_to_one_of_these(int data, const std::vector<int>& criteria)
{
    using std::end; using std::begin; using std::find;
    return end(criteria) != find(begin(criteria), end(criteria), data);
}

auto data_matches = is_equal_to_one_of_these(data, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
```

Edit:

I prefer the interface in terms of a vector, instead of an initializer list, because it is  more powerful:

```
std:vector<int> v = make_candidate_values_elsewhere();
auto data_matches = is_equal_to_one_of_these(data, v);
```

The interface (by using a vector), doesn't restrict you to define the values, where you call `is_equal_to_one_of_these`.

Comment: `static const vector` is essentially the same as `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Not quite. I would not be surprised to see `std::initializer_list` be stored in read-only memory and be sufficiently accessible to the optimizer that constant propagation and inlining might have the optimizer realize that `1 in {1, 2, 3, 4}` is always true (for example) whereas I would be much more surprised if it worked with a `vector` because of the indirection level.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I only mean functionally. Yes, if `initializer_list` weren't more efficient, it would have no reason to exist!

Comment: @utnapistim Coding algorithms against a particular container is a bad idea. What if the set is in a `std::deque`, array (std or C), or `std::set`? Better to use iterators.

Answer (score 3):

`set` is a good option, but if you really want to roll your own, initializer_list is convienient:

```
bool is_in( int val, initializer_list<int> lst )
{
    for( auto i : lst )
        if( i == val ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

use is trivial:

```
is_in( x, { 3, 5, 7 } ) ;
```

it's O(n) thou, set / unordered is faster

Comment: It is only faster when the set of numbers is already available as a set.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use standard container like [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), but that would still imply a linear complexity with worst-case runtime of `O(N)`.

```
class Foo{
public:
    int data;
    bool is_equal_to_one_of_these(const std::vector<int>& arguments){
        bool matched = false;
        for(int arg : arguments){ //if you are not using C++11: for(int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++){
            if( arg == data ){ //if you are not using C++11: if(arguments[i] == data){
                matched = true;
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }
};

std::vector<int> exampleRange{ {1,2,3,4,5} };
Foo f;
f.data = 3;
std::cout << f.is_equal_to_one_of_these(exampleRange); // prints "true"
```

Comment: all control paths does not return a value

Comment: Note: instead of setting `matched` you can simply `return true;` in the loop; this way you short-circuit it and avoid looping over all the collection when the first item matched. Also... `return std::find(arguments.begin(), arguments.end(), data) != arguments.end();`

Comment: @MatthieuM. You are right, but there are already enough answers for the `std::find` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If data, num1, .. num6 are between 0 and 31, then you can use

```
int match = ((1<<num1) | (1<<num2) | ... | (1 << num6));
if( ( (1 << data) & match ) != 0 ) ...
```

If num1 to num6 are constants, the compiler will compute match at compile time.