# Accepting a variable number of parameters of the same type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to implement a function that can take an arbitrary number of `std::size_t` variables and use them accordingly.

I wish to be able to call the function (let's call it `Foo` for the sake of argument) as follows:

```
Foo( some_other_type, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10 );
```

I tried the following:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Coords>
T Foo( T tSomething, Coords... coords );
```

But that doesn't work, and if I removed the last parameter so it was valid C++ syntax, I would have to call it as follows `Foo<1, 2, 5, 7, 10>( some_other_type );` Which is not what I wanted.

I could use variadic arguments:

```
template <typename T>
T Foo( T tSomething, ... );
```

But then I would lose the type-safety that I am looking for. So my question is, is there a way in C++11 aside from say using `std::initializer_list<std::size_t>`, which would then require me to call `Foo` as follows:

```
Foo( some_other_type, {1, 2, 5, 7, 10} );
```

And would mean I couldn't unpack the arguments to construct another type.

---

EDIT: The reason I wish to have something similar to variadic templates and why `std::initializer_list` or a recursive version of `Foo` won't work, is say I have a class `Bar` whose constructor requires a variable number of arguments depending on the specific instantiation, I wish to do something similar to the following:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Coords>
T Foo( T tSomething /*, Coords... coords*/ )
{
    Bar<sizeof...(Coords)> bar( /*coords...*/ Coords... );
    // Do stuff...
    return bar.tProperty;
}
```

But I wish to be able to call `Foo` as stated above rather than with a template list.

Comment: @nosid I've updated my question to explain why this isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Shaktal Then it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3703658 or one of the probably dozens of similar questions (which shows that we need better language support IMO).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24654191/1609356). Is my answer to a near identical question. My answer explains how to achieve uniform typing via a compile-time predicate and `static_assert()` for a useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this a bit counter-intuitive at first. You need a "typename... Coords", instead of declaring it as size_t. This is because you want the compiler to fill in the typename.

You can ensure type safety by forcing this to be used as a size_t.

```
template <typename T, typename... Coords>
T Foo( T tSomething, const Coords... coords )
{
    std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Coords)>unpacked_coords {coords...};
    for (size_t coord : unpacked_coords)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    return tSomething;

}
```

You can now call like:

```
Foo( some_other_type, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10 );
```

As you wanted :)

Comment: *"Though you may need to explicitly create your numbers as size_t"* Why would you *need* to do this?

Comment: @dyp without size_t initialization, the numbers are int, and may be a different size than size_t.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Found the problem. coords needs to be const to send ints over.

Comment: ??? I do not think that `Coords` needs to be `const` to accept ints. Do you have a minimal complete example that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes, the code I provided shows the problem when compiled on 64bit Xcode. Not sure if other 64 bit compilers would show this, but 32 bit will work for sure.